# Do you know how to install mysqlclient in Ubuntu

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Thank you!

ubantu:
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04

python == 3.6
Django == 2.2.7

Error installing mysqlclient:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_chuanzhi/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-szptn3sp/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-szptn3sp/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ls6jqm63 --python-tag cp36
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-szptn3sp/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (31 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_chuanzhi/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  /usr/bin/ld: 找不到 -lssl
  /usr/bin/ld: 找不到 -lcrypto
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_chuanzhi/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-szptn3sp/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-szptn3sp/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-6tingevf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_chuanzhi/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-szptn3sp/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (31 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_chuanzhi/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: 找不到 -lssl
    /usr/bin/ld: 找不到 -lcrypto
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_chuanzhi/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-szptn3sp/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-szptn3sp/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-6tingevf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/yangcoco/.virtualenvs/Django_chuanzhi/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

Why?

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip install pymysql
pip install mysqlclient
```

I installed the installation package I found, but still couldn't install mysqlclient

Does anyone know the correct way to install mysqlclient?

Please tell me why, thank you

Sorry, I don't understand myself. No answer found

Comment: maybe use `mysql-connector-python` created by authors of `MySQL`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: you don't have to use `mysqlclient` - you can use other module. Maybe install `mysql-connector-python` instead of `mysqlclient`  - `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Comment: [Django and mysql-connector-python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout [the project's github page](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient#prerequisites).

There're some prerequisite to install mysql client:

> - `$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config` # Debian / Ubuntu
> - `% sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel pkgconfig` # Red Hat / CentOS